# How to create a Scheduled Task in Alibaba Cloud?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

What if I want to run some tasks while some scaling activity happens like scaling up or scaling down.

I see that we have an option of Scheduled tasks. how to create one using the Alibaba cloud console?

Answer (score 0):

The steps to creating a schedule task is the following:

1. Click on **Scheduled Tasks** under **Auto-trigger task management**, that will bring the page where you can create schedule task
2. Click Create Scheduled Task, it a new dialog box should pop-up asking for the scheduled task's details
3. Fill in the fields as required and continue.

As per their documentation

- You can create up to 20 scheduled tasks according to input parameters.

You can refer to the official documentation on creating a scheduled task on Alibaba Cloud here:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25904.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create up to 20 scheduled tasks according to input parameters.

Procedure to schedule the tasks:

1. Click Scheduled task under Auto-trigger task management
2. Click Create a scheduled task
3. Enter the task name, execution time and recurrence
4. Select a scaling group and scaling rule to be triggered by the scheduled task and Click Submit.